# How to add telerik RadOrgChart in wpf app

Tags: wpf, telerik

I want to know that, is it possible to add telerik's RadOrgChart control in wpf application?

Comment: No. As far as I know RadOrgChart is an ASP.NET control.

Comment: Is there any other telerik control for wpf with same functionality?

Comment: Please refer to my answer.

Comment: your answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know that, is it possible to add telerik's RadOrgChart control in wpf application?

No. As far as I know `RadOrgChart` is an ASP.NET control

> Is there any other telerik control for wpf with same functionality?

That would probably be the `RadDiagram` control: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/raddiagram/overview